# When measuring voltages across a resistor Vab != Va - Vb

Tags: voltage

Why is measuring a voltage drop across a resistor different than when measuring the voltage before and after and subtracting them? it seemed to be around 5%, is this just random error?

Answer (score 1):

It should be the same if you're meassuring against the same ground. The problem most likely lies in meassurement error.